# Why styles are not updated dynamically inside DataTemplate on Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, themes, datatemplate, resourcedictionary

I am facing an issue where control styles are never updated dynamically when they are especially located in a DataTemplate on UWP. It is actually working on Android.

What I am trying to achieve here is to understand how to update the theme of an app by switching between two themes : Light and Dark. I found out that dynamic resources and merged dictionaries can be used for this purpose.

Here's a link to the sources : [Git](https://github.com/BrunoMoureau/theme)

Styles are applied correctly when the page is created but are not updated dynamically when the app theme changes. I use a CollectionView to display the theme options providing a custom ContentView (CheckBoxView) to the CollectionView.ItemTemplate. The user can pick a theme and it should update every controls including the ones created using DataTemplate.

Here's what it looks like :
[image: observed]

And here's what I expect it to do :
[image: expected]

Does anyone can explain this behavior ? What am I missing here ?

Regards

EDIT : Added gif instead of images

Comment: I download your project, and test it at my side, when I checked Light color, the theme likes  the first screenshot, when I checked Dark color, the theme likes the third screenshot, I don't find the theme like the second screenshot, so I think it works fine. Please try again, and see if you still have issue, and please provide one gif to describe your issue here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to say that I am experiencing this issue on UWP. I tried it out on Android and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I added gif to illustrate it better. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: I test your project at xamarin.uwp, yes, I can reproduce your issue at my side, but I can not find one solution, so I will escalate your issue for more professional to help you solve this issue, please wait a minute.

Comment: Thanks @CherryBu-MSFT, I really appreciate your support ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by updating Xamarin.Forms from v4.2.0.709249 to its last stable version (currently v4.4.0.991537).